# How to properly attach a library to CheckoutPaneForm

Tags: 8, theming

I'm attempting to attach a library to a `CommerceCheckoutPane` plugin.  I first started with using `$pane_form['#attached']['library'][] = 'commerce_paypal/express-checkout';`.  There were some errors in my `commerce_paypal.libraries.yml` file but once those were resolved the libaries still don't appear to be loaded.

Right now, my setup looks like:

**commerce_paypal.libraries.yml**:

```
paypal.checkout:
  remote: https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js
  license:
    name: MIT
    gpl-compatible: true
  js:
    https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js
express-checkout:
  js:
    js/paypal_ec.js
  dependencies:
    - commerce_paypal/paypal.checkout
```

**Drupal\commerce_paypal\Plugin\Commerce\CheckoutPane\ExpressCheckout**:

```
public function buildPaneForm(array $pane_form, FormStateInterface $form_state, array &$complete_form) {
  $pane_form['#theme'] = 'commerce_paypal_express_checkout';

  return $pane_form;
}
```

**commerce-paypal-express-checkout.html.twig**

```
{{ attach_library('commerce_paypal/express-checkout') }}

asdfas
```

**js/paypal_ec.js**:

```
console.log('here');
```

When I place the pane form I see `asdfas` but the JS is not added.  I've checked the source, no sign of paypal_ec.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual, I was messing something up.  JS libraries need `: {}`.  Updating **commerce_paypal.libraries.yml** to this solves it:

```
paypal.checkout:
  remote: https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js
  license:
    name: MIT
    gpl-compatible: true
  js:
    https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js: {}
express-checkout:
  js:
    js/paypal_ec.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - commerce_paypal/paypal.checkout
```